# Как получить массив до определённого количества?

Tags: javascript

Как от сюда вытащить первые 5 имён? Остальные не нужны

```
<div class="container">
<div class="names">
    <div class="text">
        <text type="text" class="user">Андрей</text>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <text type="text" class="user">Саша</text>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <text type="text" class="user">Василий</text>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <text type="text" class="user">Денис</text>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="names">
    <div class="text">
        <text type="text" class="user">Никита</text>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <text type="text" class="user">Сергей</text>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <text type="text" class="user">Алексей</text>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <text type="text" class="user">Иван</text>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: `for( let i = 0; i < 5; i++ )` ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.user');
elements = [...elements].slice(0, 5);
let names = elements.map(element => element.innerText);
```